# Flask redirect call in @app.before_request breaks all .css and .js

Tags: flask, redirect, mime-types

I am using Flask for developing a web application, which should also offer a maintenance mode that shows a standard 'under construction' website (nothing fancy).

I thought that is straight-forward by simply adding a redirect call in the @app.before_request method in flask, which would render my maintenance.html when I set a boolean. So I thought and here I am.

This redirect call from within the before_request method seems to break all javascript and .css definitions in the .html file to which I redirect. I tried all pages for a test with the same result. The console is full with this kind of messages

[image]

For an unknown reasons they all get the 'text/html' mime type. When I call the .html sides directly they work and .css and .js have their correct mime type.

My redirect looks fairly standard I guess as below

```
@app.route('/maintenance')
def maintenance_page():
    """ Renders the maintenance page """
    return render_template("maintenance.html", static_path='static')

@app.before_request
def pre_check_req():
    
    """" Show maintenance side if database flag is set and avoid
         cyclic re-direct by checking the request path """
    if is_under_maintenance() and request.path != url_for('maintenance_page'):
        return redirect(url_for('maintenance_page'))
```

I can reproduce this by redirecting to any of my .html websites, so its seems to be a general problem here. All websites work if accessed directly over their routes.

Does anyone have an idea where this behavior is coming from? Are there alternatives to implement a maintenance page and achieve a force-redirect under certain conditions except for the before_request route? I am thankful for any pointer!

Answer (score 2):

You're heading in a workable direction. Assuming your maintenance page needs styling you'll also need to avoid rerouting requests for static assets.

Consider changing

```
if is_under_maintenance() and request.path != url_for('maintenance_page'):
```

to

```
if reroute_for_maintenance(request.path):
```

then

```
def reroute_for_maintenance(path):
    if not is_under_maintenance():
        return False
    if path == url_for('maintenance_page'):
        return False
    # as one example, whitelist anything static
    if '/static/' in path:
        return False
    return True
```

Or, you can be more specific as to what you'll let pass through during maintenance.